# Constructing the identity element of a matrix algebra generated by a single matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Setup**: Let us define the matrix algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by a single self-adjoint matrix $M$ to be the span of all natural powers of $M$ (the matrix and the span are over complex numbers)
$$\mathcal A :=\left<M\right>=span\{M,M^2,M^3...\}.$$

**Question**: Is there an element $I_\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{A}$ that acts as the multiplicative identity on the elements of $\mathcal{A}$? Is there a constructive way to show it?

**Remarks**:

1. I know that when we have the identity matrix as part of the algebra $\left<I,M\right>$ the algebra is just the span of spectral projections (including the kernel projection) of $M$.
2. I expect the same to be true for $\left<M\right>$ (excluding the kernel projection) and the identity $I_\mathcal{A}$ to be just the sum of all the spectral projections.
3. The problems start when I try to construct the spectral projections in $\left<M\right>$ without using the identity or construct the identity $I_\mathcal{A}$ without using the spectral projections (if I have one it is easy to construct the other).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the identity element always exists. Since $M$ is diagonalisable, its minimal polynomial is in the form of $xf(x)$ or $f(x)$ where $f$ is some (possibly constant) polynomial with $f(0)\ne0$. Let $g$ be the polynomial given by $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{-f(0)}$. Then $g(0)=0$. Hence $g(M)\in\mathcal A$. Also, as $Mf(M)=0$, we have $Mg(M)=M$, i.e. $g(M)$ is the identity element in $\mathcal A$.

Comment: The general idea makes sense but I'm not sure how you got "Hence g(M)∈A". Also, is it obvious that g(M) is the identity when acting from the left (if g(M) is self adjoint than its fine but I somehow do not see that). Thanks!

Comment: @oleg $g$ is a polynomial. Let's say $g(x)=c_rx^r+c_{r-1}x^{r-1}+\cdots+c_1x+c_0$. Thus $g(M)=c_rM^r+c_{r-1}M^{r-1}+\cdots+c_1M+c_0I$. Surely $c_rM^r+c_{r-1}M^{r-1}+\cdots+c_1M\in\mathcal A$, but if $c_0\ne0$, whether $c_0I$ is a member of $\mathcal A$ will be something that we need to prove. Fortunately, by our construction, $c_0=g(0)$ is zero. So, we can be sure that $g(M)\in\mathcal A$. Also, as $g$ is a polynomial, $g(M)M=Mg(M)$. More generally, $g(M)p(M)=p(M)g(M)$ for any polynomial in $M$. In particular, $g(M)A=Ag(M)$ for every $A\in\mathcal A$.